# C - Valgrind not showing line number of a code compiled by a Makefile

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, valgrind

I use a Makefile for compile my code in C.
But when I try to use valgrind on it, I can't see the track of the leak :

Here is my Makefile :

```
SRC     =       main.c

OBJ     =       $(SRC:.c=.o)

NAME    =       valgrind_check

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJ)
        gcc -g -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)
```

Here is how I launch valgrind :

```
make
cc -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -g -o valgrind_check main.o
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./valgrind_check
```

Now the result :

```
==13934== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13934== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13934== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13934== Command: ./valgrind_check
==13934== 
==13934== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13934==    at 0x4E8B4A9: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==13934==    by 0x4E935F5: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==13934==    by 0x400501: bad_function (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934==    by 0x400524: main (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13934==    at 0x4004E6: bad_function (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934== 
==13934== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13934==    at 0x4E8792E: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==13934==    by 0x4E8B225: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==13934==    by 0x4E935F5: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==13934==    by 0x400501: bad_function (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934==    by 0x400524: main (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13934==    at 0x4004E6: bad_function (in /home/mrabaud/Repository/Valgrind/valgrind_check)
==13934==
```

As you can see, the tracking is not helpful at all.

Here the result if I run the code without makefile :

```
gcc -g -o valgrind_check main.c 
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./valgrind_check


==14056== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14056== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14056== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14056== Command: ./valgrind_check
==14056== 
==14056== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14056==    at 0x4E8B4A9: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==14056==    by 0x4E935F5: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==14056==    by 0x400501: bad_function (main.c:14)
==14056==    by 0x400524: main (main.c:22)
==14056==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14056==    at 0x4004E6: bad_function (main.c:11)
==14056== 
==14056== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14056==    at 0x4E8792E: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==14056==    by 0x4E8B225: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==14056==    by 0x4E935F5: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==14056==    by 0x400501: bad_function (main.c:14)
==14056==    by 0x400524: main (main.c:22)
==14056==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14056==    at 0x4004E6: bad_function (main.c:11)
```

How can I fixed that ? I don't have the choice, I have to use a Makefile.

Any help will be very appreciated. I have this issue this month, but found nothing...

Comment: When you run `make`, it should print the command that it runs.  What does it output?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, this was an answer of a guy who forget to add -track-origins=yes.

This is not my case. My case, as I wrote is specific to the makefile. I demonstrate that at the end of my post.

Comment: dbush you right, I modified my post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include a rule on how to build a .o file, so a default rule was used.  That default rule didn't compile main.c with the -g flag, so you get no debug info.

Add a rule for .o to spell this out:

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc -g -c $<
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I understand the problem now, but I have trouble to implement the solution.

The following rule should me modified or not ? :

$(NAME):        $(OBJ)
        gcc -g -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)

Because, if I just add the %.o on my makefile, I dont have any change on the output. 

So I suppose that the $(NAME) compile without consider the %.o rule.

Comment: @MartinRabaud Keep that rule, which creates the executable, and add the above rule, which creates the object file.